# Creating a variable from Reduce[] output in Mathematica

Tags: system-variables

Say I have the following input:

```
Reduce[{t*c==50, t==5}]
```

the output:

> ```
> t == 5. && c == 10.
> ```

Is there a way to create a variable `x` that gets assigned the value of `c` from the output without actually having to type `x = 10`?

Comment: `x = c /. ToRules @ Reduce[...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
out = Reduce[{t*c == 50, t == 5}];
x = Cases[out, c == y_ :> y, -1][[1]]
10
```

Answer (score 1):

With

```
eqs = {t*c == 50, t == 5};
```

then

```
x = Refine[c, Reduce[eqs]]
```

or (wxffles' comment)

```
x = c /. ToRules@Reduce[eqs]
```

or

```
x = c /. First@Solve[eqs]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation to `Solve` (just ran into it):

`Solve` with `Method->"Reduce"` uses `Reduce` to find solutions, but returns replacement rules:

```
Solve[{t*c == 50, t == 5}, {t, c}, Method -> Reduce]

{{t -> 5, c -> 10}}
```